# How to setup php-fpm on CentOS 7?

Tags: apache, centos, lamp, php, mod-fastcgi

There are a lot of guides out there about setup php-fpm for Apache on CentOS 5x or 6x but none of them are working on Centos 7. I searched for days but can't find any solution.

```
yum install php-fpm
```

This command succesfully working.

But then i stuck with this line:

```
yum install mod_fastcgi
```

The error is "There is no package as mod_fastcgi"

Is there any mod_fastcgi module compatible with CentOS 7? If so, how can i complete php-fpm setup? Please guide me.

My server have some trouble about memory usage. So i have to optimize Apache. Here is my "top" result.

[image]

Comment: I feel your pain. The really annoying thing about php-fpm is that the official documentation seems to be gone/unmaintained. The php-fpm website says to check php.net, but there is no information there. Most of the guides I find reference a directive FastCgiExternalServer, which errors out when I try to start Apache, even though I am loading the mod_fcgid module. *shrugs*. Where have all the people running RedHat/Centos gone?

Answer (score -1):

Deploy PHP with FastCGI

If you are using PHP code with your application, you will need to implement “PHP-FastCGI” in order to allow Nginx to properly handle and parse PHP code. You can install this via YUM from the EPEL repository that was previously installed:

```
yum install php-cli php spawn-fcgi
```